# Cannot disable a site

Tags: server, 18.04, apache2, lamp

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my server with Drupal 8

The Drupal installation is accessible from https://www.mydomaine.com

If I enter the following command:

```
sudo a2dissite www.mydomaine.com.conf
```

and

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

My site is still accessible.

Why? Normally it should be disabled.

If I enter the IP address of my server, the apache page appears. Yet the default site is disabled.

```
ubuntu@www:/etc/apache2$ cd sites-enabled
ubuntu@www:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ ls -l
total 0
```

When I type the IP address of my server, the Apache page appears. Pouting the default site is disabled:

[image: Apache page screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Skip the `.conf` prefix.

```
sudo a2dissite www.example.org
```

will work if the corresponding config file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` is `www.example.org.conf`.

Normally `a2dissite` will give you a error message, which would say that the site is not found.

Comment: I tested your solution but it does not work. I updated my question

Comment: It does not work. The "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page" page appears even though the default virtualhost is disabled